# pyspark Hive Context -- read table with UTF-8 encoding

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table in hive, And I am reading that table in pyspark df_sprk_df

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pysaprk.sql import HiveContext
sc = SparkContext()
hive_context = HiveContext(sc)
df_sprk_df = hive_context.sql('select * from databasename.tablename')
df_pandas_df = df_sprk_df.toPandas()
df_pandas_df = df_pandas_df.astype('str')
```

but when I try to convert df_pandas_df to astype of str. but I get error like

> UnicodeEnCodeError :'ascii' codec cant encode character u'\u20ac' in position

Even I tried to convert column to str one by one as

```
for cols in df_pandas_df.columns:
    df_pandas_df[cols] = df_pandas_df[cols].str.encode('utf-8')
```

but no luck, so basically how can I import hive table to dataframe in utf-8 encoding

Comment: Can you show the full traceback?

Comment: @cricket_007 its in citrix machine and I am not allowed to take screenshot either. If you are specific about any error I can provide u with that

Comment: I'm just wondering if the problem is Spark/Hive or Pandas. Since it's a Python error, I would say Pandas

Comment: Also, `HiveContext` should be considered deprecated in Spark 2.x, and you should be using `SparkSession.sql` functions after `enableHiveSupport` - https://spark.apache.org/docs/preview/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SparkSession.Builder.enableHiveSupport ... Plus, `df_sprk_df.show()` would allow you to print the dataframe without using Pandas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this workaround helped to solve this, By changing the default encoding for the session

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('UTF-8')
```

and then

```
df_pandas_df = df_pandas_df.astype(str)
```

converts whole dataframe as string df.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly casting it to string try to infer types of pandas DataFrame using following statement:

`df_pandas_df .apply(lambda x: pd.lib.infer_dtype(x.values))`

UPD:
try to perform mapping without `.str` invocation.

Maybe something like below:

```
for cols in df_pandas_df.columns:
    df_pandas_df[cols] = df_pandas_df[cols].apply(lambda x: unicode(x, errors='ignore'))
```

Comment: The above code just gives the datatype of all the columns available in the dataframe. the column which is causing problem has datatype as 'mixed' which has spl characters

Comment: I was hopying it will give 'unicode' datatype. Anyway, what you need is to perform column values mapping (encoding), without casting it to str.