# Spark.Sql not able to read Japanese (Mutltbyte charater) from hive table?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, multibyte-characters

I am writing Japanese character in the hive table as part of one of my program. Later when i am select that field from Hive i am able to read it but when i reading it from Spark.sql it is not giving me expected result .

```
spark.sql("select SQL_VAL as sql_val from abc.ac_tbl where d_name='2019-07-09_14:26:16.486' ").show()

+-------+
|sql_val|
+-------+
|      ?|
+-------+
```

Same table when query from hive it is giving output -

```
select SQL_VAL as sql_val from abc.ac_tbl where d_name='2019-07-09_14:26:16.486'
sql_val
文
```

Comment: I was able to read it without any problem. which spark version you are using? refer below link.. it may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52076651/pyspark-hive-context-read-table-with-utf-8-encoding

Comment: Hi ,
I am using 2.3 version of Spark and also i doing my coding in scala not in Pyspark.